# Redirect to web page on a specific tab

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page called ViewUpdateSchedule.aspx which contains 6 tabs. I also have another web page where I redirect the user to the ViewUpdateSchedule.aspx page. When I am redirecting the user to the ViewUpdateSchedule.aspx I want to automatically open the #tabe-15 tab.

I am able to redirect the user to the ViewUpdateSchedule.aspx but I am unable to automatically open the #tabe-15 tab.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-info nav-justified">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabe-13"><i class="icon-home"></i><span class="hidden-xs">Schedule Details</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabe-14"><i class="icon-user"></i><span class="hidden-xs">Software Details</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabe-16"><i class="icon-envelope-open"></i><span class="hidden-xs">Contact Details</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabe-15"><i class="icon-envelope-open"></i><span class="hidden-xs">Voice (TTS) Details</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabe-17"><i class="icon-envelope-open"></i><span class="hidden-xs">Notes</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabe-18"><i class="icon-envelope-open"></i><span class="hidden-xs">Audit Trail</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

//This is where I redirect the user from one web page to the  ViewUpdateSchedule.aspx page and make an attempt to open the #tabe-15 tab

c#

```
Response.Redirect("ViewUpdateSchedule.aspx" + "#tabe-15");
```

Please assist me how I can redirect the user and automatically open the #tabe-15 tab. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to [invoke the tab select with some scripts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#via-javascript).

---

#### On `ViewUpdateSchedule.aspx` page

Inside the `<script>` tag, or better yet a separate `.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //... The rest of your code

    // This will give you #tabe-15 (or whatever ID you're sending in from server)
    var tabId = window.location.hash;

    // Select the tab
    $('a[href="' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
})
```

Alternatively, you could register a handler that will do the selecting via [RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: This will work but I can't do that because if the user accesses the ViewUpdateSchedule.aspx page from another place it will always open the #tabe-15 tab.

Comment: Could you please define "accessing this same page from another place"? I believe as long as the tab ID is not sent along, it should select the default tab.

Comment: Please see my edits. You're most likely going to need to go the script route though.

Comment: Thanks. I will post an answer as soon as I fix it